# c# Fill a listview with items from a richtextbox (each 5 lines into columns)

Tags: c#, listview, richtextbox

I have a list view and a richtextbox.
This richtextbox has data like below. And I want to input the first 5 lines in one row and 5 columns like below.
[richtextbox example and List view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTqBL.jpg)

I have the below code so far

```
for ( int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Count(); i++)
{
    string[] arry = new string[5];
    ListViewItem itms;

    arry[0] = richTextBox1.Lines[i];
    arry[1] = richTextBox1.Lines[i+1];
    arry[2] = richTextBox1.Lines[i + 1];
    arry[3] = richTextBox1.Lines[i+2];
    arry[4] = richTextBox1.Lines[i+3];

    itms = new ListViewItem(arry);
    listView1.Items.Add(itms);      
}
```

But it is not giving me the desired output, as it repeats itself over and over like seen here
[Undesired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxkpu.jpg)

Kindy let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is going line by line, not by groups of 5 lines.

Change it to this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Count(); i += 5)
```